# Mostrar sólo las columnas que contengan diferentes valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me explico, estoy haciendo una consulta en `SQL Server` como la siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE NAME LIKE '%DEMO%'
```

Esta consulta arroja dos resultados, los cuales algunas columnas comparten los mismos datos pero otras no

Hay alguna forma de mostrar sólo las columnas que sean diferentes entre los distintos resultados?

Os dejo un ejemplo, aquí traigo dos resultados con dos columnas que no coinciden entre sí, pero el resto si. Me gustaría mostrar sólo las que sean diferentes, una especie de SELECT columna1, columna2.... dinámico.

[image: Imagen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori sin un ejemplo más claro, podrías realizar un unpivot sobre las columnas.

```
create table dbo.ejCustomer
             (
             supriesgoase varchar(10)
           , tarifa       tinyint
           , tipfac       varchar(10)
           , tipiva       varchar(10)
           , tipoCliente  varchar(10)
           , tipRiesgo    varchar(10)
           , tipTra       varchar(10)
             );
go

insert into dbo.ejCustomer(supriesgoase
                     , tarifa
                     , tipfac
                     , tipiva
                     , tipoCliente
                     , tipRiesgo
                     , tipTra)
values
       ( 'F', 1, 'T', 'ORD21', 'C', 'AF', NULL ),
       ( 'F', 1, 'T', 'EXE', 'C', 'PAF', NULL );
GO
```

Sobre el escenario, puedes hacer una tabla derivada y sobre ella leer los valores utilizando la función MIN, para agruparlos por supriesgoase y tarifa, mostrando como null, si los valores de cada fila son iguales a "la fila agrupada", y sino el valor de la columna. Luego sobre la salida de esta query, realizar el unpivot.

```
select upv.supriesgoase, upv.tarifa, upv.columna, upv.columnas as alias from (
select 
          e.supriesgoase
        , e.tarifa
        , case when e.tipfac = c.tipfac then null else e.tipfac end as tipfac
        , case when e.tipiva = c.tipiva then null else e.tipiva end as tipiva
        , case when e.tipocliente = c.tipocliente then null else e.tipocliente end as tipocliente
        , case when e.tipriesgo = c.tipriesgo then null else e.tipriesgo end as tipriesgo
        , case when e.tiptra = c.tiptra then null    else e.tiptra  end as tiptra
        from ejcustomer as e
              inner join (
                          select supriesgoase
                               , tarifa
                               , min(tipfac) as tipfac
                               , min(tipiva) as tipiva
                               , min(tipocliente) as tipocliente
                               , min(tipriesgo) as tipriesgo
                               , min(tiptra) as tiptra
                                from dbo.ejcustomer
                                group by supriesgoase
                                        , tarifa
                          ) as c
                          on e.supriesgoase = c.supriesgoase and e.tarifa = c.tarifa
) as source
 unpivot (  columna for columnas in 
                                    ( 
                                    tipfac, tipiva, tipocliente, tipriesgo, tiptra
                                    )) as upv
```

[image: Resultado]

También podrías realizar algo dinámico.